Equivalent definitions for radical extensions
I find out $2$ different definitions for a finite separable extension $E/k$ to be radical:
Definition I:
There exists a finite extension $M/k$ containing $E$ and a tower of fields:
$$ k=M_0\subseteq M_1\subseteq \dots \subseteq M_n=M$$
such that
$$ M_{i+1}=M_i(\gamma_i)$$
where $\gamma_i\in M_{i+1}$ and $\gamma_i^{m_i}\in M_i$.
Definition II: (From Serge Lang)
There exists a finite extension $M/k$ containing $E$ and a tower of fields:
$$ k=M_0\subseteq M_1\subseteq \dots \subseteq M_n=M$$
such that
$M_{i+1}=M_{i}(\alpha)$ is one of the following types:

$\alpha$ is a root of unity.

$\alpha$ is a root of polynomial $x^n-a\in M_i[x]$, where $n$ is coprime to the characteristic.

$\alpha$ is a root of polynomial $x^p-x-a\in M_i[x]$, where $p=$ the characteristic.


My question: Are these $2$ definitions equivalent?
It follows from Artin-Schreier theorem that definition I implies definition II. But what about the converse? I have no idea how the case (3) in definition II implies definition I.
Thanks a lot for your help:)
